# Nested attribute validations not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been struggling with this for some time now. I'm just trying to get nested attributes to validate on Rails 3.2 with no luck. It's like it's just completely ignoring validations for the nested attributes. Below is an example validation that's not working:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :description, :presence => true
  belongs_to  :client_branch
  has_many    :invoice_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_items, :allow_destroy => true
end

class InvoiceItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :invoice
  validate :thisisatest

  def thisisatest
    errors.add(:qty, 'QTY NOT VALIDATING TEST.')
  end
end
```

When saving an Invoice with some InvoiceItems, it saves it successfully, even though the custom validation is clearly adding an error for the :qty attribute. Is there something I should be adding to my models for nested validation to work, or am I perhaps missing something else?

Comment: When the invoice is saved, is the invoice item also saved? Do you use attr_accessible? Do you have :invoice_item_attributes listed as attr_accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm being daft. I changed the model name, along with all references to it and it took me this long to miss one reference still pointing to the old model in the javascript. Thus, items being added dynamically weren't named correctly, causing the validation not to trigger. :/